# Emitted hair particles are pointing one direction

Tags: 3d-view, particles, hair

When I try to emit branches from a tree, all of them are trying to point into one direction, it looks like if they were following a path. Also, they doesn't sit on the tree itself they just randomly float around it. I've tried many things I found online, for example:

-Enableing rotation under advanced settings and rotating.

-Using modifier Stack

-Rotating the branch itself

-applying all transforms

but none of them seemed to work.
Can someone help please, I've been struggleing for days now.
Thanks!
You can find the project files on this link: https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1q65u3Pf2utAFqM-MnEINlLLyMt6uAK9M?usp=sharing
[image: It looks like this now]

Comment: Move the leaf mesh in edit mode so that the stem is at the object's origin point (orange dot).

Comment: Sadly, this didn't solve the problem, the branches still floating and pointing in one direction. I tried rotating the leafs in edit mode on different axises, but that didn't help either. The origin point was at the stem in all cases (I moved the 3D cursor to it and than moved the origin point to the 3D cursor)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. select branch, set location to 0

[image]

2. set tracking axis like this:

[image]

3. set children to none

[image]

4. raise your number here:

[image]

result for 500  (emission number)

[image]

and just a hint: you can make even better and more customizable trees with geometry nodes, e.g. watch this: https://youtu.be/9mkJg6BZ65k

Comment: This really worked! Thanks a lot! This was a life saver.

Comment: Glad i could help

Comment: Thanks for the tip at the end with making even better trees. This was my second experience with geometry nodes (After Andrew's donut tutorial). It took a day, but I'm glad I tried it. So I made this:
*Edit: Sorry i didn't know I can't attach pictures to comments.*

Comment: You are welcome. If you want another tip:search and watch tutorials of Polyfjord. He is making the best tutorials for Blender right now (just my opinion)

Comment: I will check him out, thanks!